# Bypass Set up Internet Explorer 11 pop up window using powershell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I try to bypass [Windows IE setting pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMHDx.png) from the initial launch IE. either close the window or click ask later. Is it possible Powershell can check the window object? I tried the **"New-Object"** below:

```
New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
```

But it doesn't seem to work that way I expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is using group policy out of the question as this can easily be done through a gpo. Here is a link explaining. https://mkcheah88.blogspot.com/2014/06/microsoft-how-to-disable-internet.html

If not is it ok to change the registry key this links to with powershell prior to internet explorer opening? If so I can modify this answer to include that answer.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for the Registry method (or Powershell), this is the script I use:

```ps
$keyPath = 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main'

if (!(Test-Path $keyPath)) {
    New-Item $keyPath -Force
}


Set-ItemProperty `
    -Path $keyPath `
    -Name "DisableFirstRunCustomize" `
    -Value 1
```

You want to test the path exists first as using the `-Force` parameter on `New-Item` will remove any existing children of the path provided.